# How to use multiple & in scss?

Tags: css, sass, less

when i tried to convert this less code to scss.

```
.a {
  &-b&-c {
    color: white;
  }
}
```

error occur like this:

```
Error at Ln 2,Col 8:
Invalid CSS after "-b": expected "{", was "&-c"

"&-c" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector.
```

How to use multiple & in scss?

Comment: [This link to the docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector) should help you out

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation):

```
.a {
  &-b#{&}-c {
    color: white;
  }
}
```